# How to redirect to a seperate page in AMP website

Tags: php, redirect, amp-html

I have created a AMP form after filling the form it should redirect to thank you page :

```
<form on="tap:my-lightbox"  custom-validation-reporting="show-all-on-submit" action-xhr="https://example.com/amp/nextown/test.php" method="post" target="_blank" role="form">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="lblname" placeholder="Name*" required pattern="\w+\s\w+">
            <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing" validation-for="lblname"></span>
            <span visible-when-invalid="patternMismatch" validation-for="lblname">
             </span>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="lblemail" placeholder="Email Address*" required="text">
              <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing" validation-for="lblemail"></span>
              <span visible-when-invalid="typeMismatch" validation-for="lblemail"></span>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="lblphone" placeholder=" Phone Number*" required="text"></div>
           <div class="col-md-12 but-mdsubmit">                                
              <input id="popup_sub" type="submit" value="SEND ENQUIRY" >
          </div>


        </div>
      </form>
```

**test.php** code :

```
$domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
$redirect_url = 'https://example.com/amp/nextown/thankyou.amp.html';


if($_POST['name']!="" && $_POST['email']!="" && $_POST['phone']!=""){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['phone'];
    $source= "NA";
    $medium = "NA";
    $campaign = "NA";
    $vserv= "NA";
    $state="NA";
    $city = "NA";
    $dialing_code='91';
    $country='India';
    $project_id ='284';
    $client_id ='4';
    $ind_project_id='';

    $crm_url = "http://exampleapi.com/campaign/fetch_data/".urlencode($name)."/".urlencode($email)."/".urlencode($mobile)."/284/".urlencode($source)."/".urlencode($medium)."/".urlencode($campaign)."/4/NA/NA/".urlencode($dialing_code)."";

    if(file_get_contents($crm_url)){


        header("Content-type: application/json");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.ampproject.org");
        header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://netbizlabs.com");
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin, AMP-Redirect-To");
        header ('AMP-Redirect-To: '.$redirect_url);

        //echo json_encode(array('successmsg'=>'My success message. [It will be displayed shortly(!) if with redirect]'));


        exit;
    }

}
```

But it is not redirecting, what I am doing wrong please help me on this as I am new in AMP website development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with following code as posted in my answer if not work let me know

Answer (score 0):

Replace the condition code

```
 if(file_get_contents($crm_url)){
        $domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ". str_replace('.', '-','https://netbizlabs.com') .".cdn.ampproject.org");
        header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: " . $domain_url);
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
        header("AMP-Redirect-To: https://example.com/amp/nextown/thankyou.amp.html");
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin"); 
        echo json_encode(array('successmsg'=>'data post'));
        exit;
}
```